# Number of terms in an Arithmetic Series between 2 limits

Tags: sequences-and-series

consider an Arithmetic Series such as   2 + 5 + 8 + 11 + 14 + ...   (a = 2, d = 3)
     Also, consider an Upper Bound, say, U = 13

I'm hoping to get an **explicit expression for the NUMBER of TERMS**, T, where the last term is  <= U.

So...
for a = 2, d = 3, U = 13:   The expression should give T = 4.
for a = 2, d = 3, U = 14:   The expression should give T = 5.

More generally, I'm hoping to know an expression for the NUMBER of TERMS, T, where the first term >= L (the Lower Bound), and the last term is  <= U (the Upper Bound).

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Recall the following formula for arithmetic sequences:
$$
t_T = a + (T - 1)d \iff T = \frac{t_T - a}{d} + 1
$$
Let's assume that $d > 0$. Then for the upper bound, we want to find the largest integer $T$ such that $t_T \leq U$, which would be:
$$
T = \left\lfloor \frac{U - a}{d} \right\rfloor + 1
$$

Comment: Thank you.  I'll try to use your reasoning to consider the number of terms between an Upper and a Lower bound.